# Modify the robot_description parameter at runtime

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-kinetic, ros-industrial, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to put identified offsets to the nominal URDF-values of my industrial robot. Since I do not want to modify the support package of my robot, I thought a good way to insert the identified rotary and translation offsets would be to change the `robot_description` on the parameter server.
Is there a more elegant way to fulfill my goal, or do I really have to modify the string from the `robot_description` parameter?
Is it even possible or advisable to change values of the robot description at runtime?

Thanks for all recommendations.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313954/modify-the-robot_description-parameter-at-runtime/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2019-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:\

> Is it even possible or advisable to change values of the robot description at runtime?

it's possible, but there are a whole host of potential issues with it.

I can't find them right now, but there have been discussions about this in the past. Main issue is that consumers of URDFs do not ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:
.. expect the parameter (so `robot_description`) to ever change. So even if you update it, almost no readily available software that consumes URDF/XACRO will ever load it more than once, and will not see your updated content.

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-28**:
Well that sounds pretty disappointing. Are there any possibilities to include my identified URDF-Offsets, without directly changing the URDF then?

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-28**:\

> it's possible, but there are a whole host of potential issues with it.

That's what I thought. I figured that the robot description is probably loaded once by all instances, that use it (like moveit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To close this: It seems like that modifying the URDF is the only "proper" way of modifying the robot_desription parameter, so that it can be used by any software consumer, that reads the URDF/XACRO.

The [robot_calibration](https://github.com/mikeferguson/robot_calibration) package does the same thing:
Calibrated results are stored inside of a new modified urdf file.

---

Originally posted by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) with karma: 143 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:
You might want to take a look at the YAML support in xacro. See [ros-industrial/universal_robot#371](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/371) for a prototype of how that can be used for these kind of use-cases.